# Regex for <span> tag with style attribute

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

How could I match a text between a span opening and closing tags with style attribute?:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">some text</span>
```

I tried the following pattern but it doesn't work:

```
<span style=\"white-space: pre-line\">(.*)</span>
```

Comment: Are you asking us for a regex? If so then lookup the look behind and lookahead assertations

Comment: Actually I understand that it's a bad idea to search html with a regex. Now I'm looking how to convert html text to a plain one.

Comment: I would suggest suing the nuget package: HTML Agility Pack https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack. It makes HTML traversal very easy

Comment: Thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [it is in general a bad idea to parse HTML with a Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

It would be better to use a solution to parse HTML, like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

That said, if you need help with Regular Expressions, you can download a tool that will help you analyze and test them. There are several tools available for that, I personally like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm).

In this particular case, I think you are having problems with the spaces, but I cannot be sure since you are not showing the RegexOptions you are using to build your Regex. Try

```
<span\s*style=\"white-space:\s*pre-line\">(.*)</span>
```

Comment: @MaximilianAst: why should it be necessary to escape the `/`?

Comment: Sry my bad. Forgot that `/` hasn't to be escaped in .NET